# How to generalize this regex so that it starts capturing substrings at the beginning of a string or if it is followed by some other word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

name = "John"

#In these examples it works fine
input_sense_aux = "These sound system are too many, I think John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer"
#input_sense_aux = "These sound system are too many but I know that John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer"
#input_sense_aux = "These sound system are too many but I know that John can help us. otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer"
#input_sense_aux = "Do you know if John with the others could come this afternoon?"

#In these examples it does not work well
#input_sense_aux = "John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer"
#input_sense_aux = "Can you help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for John"
#input_sense_aux = "sorry! can you help us? otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for John"



regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*?" + name + r"\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*\??"
m1 = re.search(regex_patron_m1, input_sense_aux, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code
if m1:
    something_1, something_2 = m1.groups()

    something_1 = something_1.strip()
    something_2 = something_2.strip()

    print(repr(something_1))
    print(repr(something_2))
```

I need the **regex** to **grab the content before "John"** like this:

`(start of sentence|¿|¡|,|;|:|(|[|.) \s* "content for something_1" \s* John`

And then:

`John \s* "content for something_2" \s* (end of sentence|?|!|,|;|:|)|]|.)`

In the fists examples, the regex works fine:

```
'these teams are too many but I know that'
'can help us'
```

```
'Do you know if'
'with the others could come this afternoon'
```

But with the cases of the last 3 examples the regex does not return anything

And I need help to be able to generalize my regex to all these cases and at the same time respect the conditions in which it must extract the content of `something_1` and `something_2`

For the 3 last examples, the expected results are:

```
''
' can help us'
```

```
' otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for '
''
```

```
' otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for '
''
```

Comment: What is the expected result for the last 3 examples?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edit the question now including that which I omitted, I thought it would be clear when indicating the desired patterns, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re

name = "John"

input_sense_auxs = [
    "These sound system are too many, I think John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer",
    "These sound system are too many but I know that John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer",
    "These sound system are too many but I know that John can help us. otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer",
    "Do you know if John with the others could come this afternoon?",

    "John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer",
    "Can you help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for John",
    "sorry! can you help us? otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for John"]

regex_patron_m1 = fr'(?:^|[?!¿¡,;:([.])\s*(?:(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*)?{name}(?:\s*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*))?\s*(?:$|[]?!,;:).])'
# r"\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*?" + name + r"\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*\??"
for input_sense_aux in input_sense_auxs:
    print(f'--- {input_sense_aux} ---')
    m1 = re.search(regex_patron_m1, input_sense_aux, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code
    if m1:
        something_1, something_2 = m1.groups()

        something_1 = something_1.strip() if something_1 else ""
        something_2 = something_2.strip() if something_2 else ""

        print(repr(something_1))
        print(repr(something_2))
```

Output:

```
--- These sound system are too many, I think John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer ---
'I think'
'can help us'
--- These sound system are too many but I know that John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer ---
'These sound system are too many but I know that'
'can help us'
--- These sound system are too many but I know that John can help us. otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer ---
'These sound system are too many but I know that'
'can help us'
--- Do you know if John with the others could come this afternoon? ---
'Do you know if'
'with the others could come this afternoon'
--- John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer ---
''
'can help us'
--- Can you help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for John ---
'otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for'
''
--- sorry! can you help us? otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for John ---
'otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for'
''
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yJ09k7).

*Details*:

- `(?:^|[?!¿¡,;:([.])\s*(?:(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*)?` - the prefix, the left-hand side part, that matches

  - `(?:^|[?!¿¡,;:([.])` - either start of string or a char from the `?!¿¡,;:([.` set
  - `\s*`  - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s*)?` - an optional occurrence of

    - `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` - Group 1: one or more word chars and then zero or more sequences of one or more whitespaces and one or more word chars
    - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `John` - the name
- `(?:\s*(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*))?\s*(?:$|[]?!,;:).])` - the right-hand part:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*))?` - Group 2: an optional sequence of one or more word chars and then zero or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces followed with one or more word chars
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `(?:$|[]?!,;:).])` - end of string or a char from the `]?!,;:).` charset.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/CIOMus/1).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, and sorry I didn't include that in my original question. How did I say I thought it was clear when I indicated the model pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Take this improved version of the code alongside some explanation, so you can customize it how you want:

```py
import re

name = "John"

#In these examples it works fine
# input_sense_aux = "These sound system are too many, I think John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer"
#input_sense_aux = "These sound system are too many but I know that John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer"
# input_sense_aux = "These sound system are too many but I know that John can help us. otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer"
# input_sense_aux = "Do you know if John with the others could come this afternoon?"

#In these examples it does not work well
# input_sense_aux = "John can help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer"
# input_sense_aux = "Can you help us, otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for John"
# input_sense_aux = "sorry! can you help us? otherwise it will be waiting for a while longer for John"



regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*([\?:\w\s]+)?\s*" + name + r"\s*([\?:\w\s]+)?\s*"
m1 = re.search(regex_patron_m1, input_sense_aux, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code
if m1:
    something_1, something_2 = m1.groups()

    if not something_1 is None:
        something_1 = something_1.strip()
        print(repr(something_1))
    if not something_2 is None:
        something_2 = something_2.strip()
        print(repr(something_2))
```

In the first two examples that did not work you have put John at the start/end of the string. This means that one of the two `something` variables could be `None`. I have fixed you code to check for that.

Now to the regex:

This was the original: `r"\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*?" + name + r"\s*((?:\w\s*)+)\s*\??"`

I made the following changes:

- Removed `\??` from the end. A questionmark is a quantifier and means "once or none" but you already have `*` for spaces which means "zero or mire times" so you have two quantifiers in a row, which is not needed
- Changed the inner statements from `()` to `[]`. round brackets are for groups, for example to get a certain part of the string, square brackets are for character groups to check "is any of these characters here?". You are currently checking if there are word-characters `\w`, spaces `\s`, colons `:` or questionmarks `?` present. To check for more you would have to add characters inside the square brackets, but beware: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : - #` need to be escaped with a preceeding backslash `\`
- Made the character groups optional with `?`. When "John" is the first part of the string, you dont have something to match in front of it. Therefore your regex fails. By making the before- and after-part optional, you can also match those strings

If you have any remaining questions feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much but I found a little problem when you put something like this in the input `ashjasjhas! Do you know if John with the others could come this afternoon? assaassa`

Comment: The problem is that instead of starting after the `!` and end before the sign `?` , what it does is include this previous text `ashjasjhas` and this later text `assaassa`

Comment: If you want to match only words and spaces use this: r"\s*([\w\s]+)?\s*" + name + r"\s*([\w\s]+)?\s*"